# Hide svg parts on print

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, highcharts

Is there any possibility to hide parts of svg at print layout.

Specialy i like to hide highstock *rangeSelector* and *navigator* will printing page.

This should work without js triggert buttons.
It should work when browsers print button was used.

Is there any possibility to show / hide an element with css media=print and bind this event with jquery?

Need to hide on the yellow parts on print layout:
http://i49.tinypic.com/24mbxop.png

for this example:

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart : {
                renderTo : 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Comment: Yes, `display: none;visibility: hidden;` on the elements, class or ID of the svg part. This offcourse in the media=print

Comment: But those elements have no id class. It needs to be done by javascript

Comment: With jQuery this can be done with [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 7):

What @Bondye said.

Create a class something like

```
@media print {
    .unprintable {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

And apply the class to the svg elements you don't want to print

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="50"  cy="50"  r="40" fill="red" />
   <circle cx="150" cy="50"  r="40" fill="red" />
   <circle cx="50"  cy="150" r="40" fill="blue" class="unprintable" />
   <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="40" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

And you try to print, the blue circle will be invisible.

http://jsfiddle.net/EqDGQ/

If `visibility: hidden;` doesn't work for you, try `display: none;` as well.

## EDITED

If you cannot add the class when they are drawn, use Javascript to add that class after the page loads.

You can't use hide(), because it will remove the elements from screen as well. You'll have to open a new tab/window and call hide(), but as it is mentioned in the question, users may use the browser menu to print. Then, you don't have the chance to open a new tab/window and call hide() .

So, you must add the .unprintable class when the page loads. Then, on the screen everything is shown, but on print, .unprintable elements won't be printed.

If you post a link to the site, and tell me what you want to hide, I can help you write the JS code, but it will be something like: http://jsfiddle.net/EqDGQ/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('svg circle[fill="blue"]').attr('class', 'unprintable');
});
```

## ----------------

## Edited Again! :)

I wrote this JS function (jQuery needed), that adds the ".unprintable" class to all the svg elements within a rectangular area:

```
setUnprintableArea = function(id, xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax, rightAligned) {
    if (rightAligned) {
        svgWidth = $('#'+id+' .highcharts-container svg')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        xMin += svgWidth;
        xMax += svgWidth;
    }
    $('#'+id+' .highcharts-container svg *').filter(function() {
        rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        return (xMin <= rect.left && rect.right  <= xMax &&
                yMin <= rect.top  && rect.bottom <= yMax);
    }).attr('class', 'unprintable');
};
```

and you can call this function like this:

```
setUnprintableArea('container', 15, 45, 240, 70); // Zoom
setUnprintableArea('container', -55, 15, 0, 40, true); // Top-right Buttons
setUnprintableArea('container', 0, 430, Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MAX_VALUE); // Horiz Scroll Bar
```

If you need to hide something that is right-aligned, set the `rightAligned` param to `true` to set the y-axis to the right edge of the svg (meaning x=0 at the right edge) and adjust xMin and xMax accordingly.

I put this on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DXYne/1/

Can this be a solution?

Comment: Good idea but not this easy solve. Try here to add the unprintable class for "zoom controlls", "date range controll" and "x axis focus" http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Comment: Thx haejeong, it works but not realy reliable. Have alook at: http://jsfiddle.net/DXYne/6/  It only works for half of elements.Please enable/ disable the DEBUG_GREEN for test.

Comment: actualy i do what i tried to avoid, because of the complicated updates. I have patched the highstock class. I addet the css classes directly. For "zoom controlles" and most controlls of "date range controlls" it works fine. Actualy only the date range min chart is left.

Answer (score 2):

The above is true, but for an approach that doesn't introduce new a css class, Javascript (even though I love it so), or runtime logic:

```
@media print {
    svg circle[fill="blue"] { 
       display:none; 
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: good point! Something simple as hiding blue circle is easy, but if the logic on what to hide become complex, CSS will becomes as complex. Also there are things you wouldn't be able to achieve using pure CSS, such as hiding all the circles that are placed below a horizontal line. But your solution is definitely more elegant in this example! Thanks.

Comment: I think you could still use CSS in less you're doing something really crazy with the layout.

hr + svg circle[fill=blue] or
.class > svg circle[fill=blue]

Comment: @Jesse my thoughts exactly. OP just wants to hide 2-3 elements; less code, more beer. Just my opinion.